# Dynamically load Jquery into .js page

Tags: jquery, dynamic, load

Please excuse me if I'm simple here, I want to create a simple widget that people can access from their websites - e.g by copy/past something like

```
<script language="javascript" src="test2.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

anywhere in their web pages. where  is dynamically filled via Jquery and the functions in/on test2.js.

I can do it if JQuery is actually "printed" on the page of test2.js, but I cannot get any JQuery functions to work if I try to include/call JQuery dynamically.  How do you call JQuery via javascript and then get it to work with the functions on the page?

And/Or is there an easy way to add the <`div id="test"></div>` dynamically aswell? Sure I can body.append etc.  but that only adds at the bottom of the page.  Is there a way to .append in the position where the script include

```
<script language="javascript" src="test2.js"></script>
```

is actually placed?

Hope I make sence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your question whether `<div id="test"></div>` can be added dynamically at the position of the script:

If you call `document.write` in your script, then this content is inserted into the document after the script.

E.g.:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <div id="first">
       <div id="second">
           <script type="text/javascript">
               document.write('<h2>test</h2>');
           </script>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

results in

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <div id="first">
       <div id="second">
           <script type="text/javascript">
               document.write('<h2>test</h2>');
           </script>
           <h2>test</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype) {
        if (filetype == "js") { //if filename is a external JavaScript file
            var fileref = document.createElement('script')
            fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
            fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
        }
        else if (filetype == "css") { //if filename is an external CSS file
            var fileref = document.createElement("link")
            fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
            fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
            fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
        }
        if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }

    loadjscssfile("jquery-1.4.2.js", "js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
```

you jquery code should be placed at the bottom of the page now to wait for jquery library to be attached in the head